# Passing a variable through to an array mid string

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [
    'Hey there, ' + name + '!',
    'It\'s nice to see ' + name + ' join us.',
    'Everybody welcome ' + name + '!',
    'Thanks,' + name
]
```

I get an error stating that `name` is undefined, so if I put `name = '';` before it, and loop through the array, it just says

```
Hey there, !
It's nice to see  join us.
Everybody welcome !
Thanks,
```

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
name = 'Albz'
console.log(array[0]);
```

and have it echo out

```
Hey there, Albz!
```

The `name` variable is dynamic and changes on each iteration of `forEach`, so it can't be hardcoded, and I'd like to not have to redeclare the array every single time as it's quite lengthy.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Make those array elements functions and let them receive the name as a parameter.

Comment: "*redeclare the array every single time*" - why that? You don't have to hardcode it only to evaluate it multiple times. Please post your whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var nameArr = ['Ayan', 'Arnab', 'Akash'];

function process(name) {
  return [
    'Hey there, ' + name + '!',
    'It\'s nice to see ' + name + ' join us.',
    'Everybody welcome ' + name + '!',
    'Thanks,' + name
  ];
}
for (var i = 0, len = nameArr.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  console.log(process(nameArr[i])[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and you!